# How to approach this with longest path technique of the following problem

Tags: graph-theory

Let k ≥ 3 and δ ≥ 2. Prove that if G is a simple graph such that δmin(G) ≥ δ and every cycle of G has length at least k, then G contains a cycle of length at least (δ − 1)(k − 2) + 2.

Comment: Well, the first step to approach this problem with *any* technique is by trying. I am inclined to spend effort answering a question if I see that the asker has made any effort to ask it. In particular, this website is not a place to go if you want someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I never told you to give me a full solution. I mentioned in my title that I need to know the approach to solve this problem. If you don't know about starting, how can you post something? I never ask to solve it for me and I know what is the use of of this website.

Comment: No, actually, you mentioned in your title that you already know the approach to solve this problem. Have you *tried* that approach? Where do you get stuck? Can you prove a weaker statement? (Also, your entire question is a command: "Prove that [...]" Which is a bit rude and also does sound a lot like asking for a full solution.)